# Question with regards to proof of $X$ and $Y$ have same law then $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ have the same law

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real-valued random variables on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb P)$ and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be some measurable map.

Show that $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ have the same law.

Proof:

Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$, then $\mathbb P( f(X) \in A)=\mathbb P(X\in f^{-1}(A))=\mathbb P(Y\in f^{-1}(A))=\mathbb P(f(Y)\in A)$ using the fact that $f^{-1}(A)$ is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ by the measurability of $f$.

This proof is clear although in one step I am having trouble that there is no more information given to $f$.

Why is $\{f(X)\in A\}=\{X\in f^{-1}(A)\}$? Surely more information needs to given on $f$, whether it is surjective etc.?

My attempt, by definition:

$$\{f(X)\in A\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:f(X(\omega))\in A\}$$
$$\{ X \in f^{-1}(A)\}=\{\omega\in \Omega :X(\omega)\in f^{-1}(A)\}$$

$"\{f(X)\in A\}\subseteq \{ X \in f^{-1}(A)\}"$

Let $\omega\in \Omega$ such that $f(X(\omega))\in A\implies \exists a \in A:f(X(\omega))=a\implies X(\omega)\in f^{-1}(\{a\})\subseteq f^{-1}(A)$

$" \{ X \in f^{-1}(A)\}\subseteq \{f(X)\in A\}"$

Let $\omega\in \Omega$ such that $X(\omega) \in f^{-1}(A)$, then $\exists a \in A$ such that $X(\omega)\in f^{-1}(\{a\})\implies f(X(\omega))=a\implies f(X(\omega))\in A$

and thus $\{ X \in f^{-1}(A)\}=\{f(X)\in A\}$.

It seems as though I did not additional assumptions of surjectivity or injectivity. In what context do I need surjectivity or injectivity?

Comment: Is your question "When do we need surjectivity or injectivity**in general?**" Or in other words, what might an answer to your question look like? In this example, the only important thing you need for the equality $\{f(X)\in A\} = \{X\in f^{-1}(A)\}$ is that $f$ is a function, not even measurability is necessary for that. The important thing is that $f$ maps each point in its domain to only one point in the codomain. In other words, it is essentially the definition of preimage of a function that does the work in this case.